# How to split each value of foreach statement with different classes PHP

Tags: php, html

I need to split up each return `$val` with different class. Let's say the value has `7` value inside and I wish to have each value have different classes.

```
foreach ($arrNum as $val) {
   ?>
      <li class="col-15"><?php echo $val; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
```

i try amend with below code , its seems not working :

```
foreach ($arrNum as $i => $val) {
                                            ?>
                                            <?php if($i == 0): ?>
                                            <div class="col-03">
                                            <?php elseif($i == 1): ?>
                                            <div class="col-28">
                                            <?php elseif($i == 2): ?>
                                            <div class="col-15">
                                            <?php elseif($i == 3): ?>
                                            <div class="col-48">
                                            <?php elseif($i == 4): ?>
                                            <div class="col-02">
                                            <?php elseif($i == 5): ?>
                                            <div class="col-46">
                                            <?php elseif($i == 6): ?>
                                            <div class="col-33">
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                                Rest of html
                                            </div>
                                           <!--  <li class="col-15"><?php echo $val; ?></li> -->
                                        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Replace col-15 by a counter ? `'col-'.$i++` of course init $i before the loop

Comment: Just a hint: Don't forget about `htmlspecialchars`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you looking for something like this `PHP-Code`

```
<?php
  // Create array
  $arrNum = array();
  $arrNum['03'] = 'Rest of html';
  $arrNum['28'] = 'Rest of html';
  $arrNum['15'] = 'Rest of html';
  $arrNum['48'] = 'Rest of html';
  $arrNum['02'] = 'Rest of html';
  $arrNum['46'] = 'Rest of html';
  $arrNum['33'] = 'Rest of html';

  foreach ($arrNum as $i=>$val) {
     echo '<div class="col-'.$i.'">'.$val.'</div>';
  }
?>
```

this will return `HTML-Code`

```
<div class="col-03">Rest of html</div>
<div class="col-28">Rest of html</div>
<div class="col-15">Rest of html</div>
<div class="col-48">Rest of html</div>
<div class="col-02">Rest of html</div>
<div class="col-46">Rest of html</div>
<div class="col-33">Rest of html</div>
```

if your text ("Rest of html") is every time the same you can simplify the code

```
<?php
  $arrNum = array('03', '28', '15', '48', '02', '46', '33');
  foreach ($arrNum as $i) {
     echo '<div class="col-'.$i.'">Rest of html</div>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Hi so i just implement <li class="col-0">Tom</li>
<li class="col-1">Lisa</li>
<li class="col-2">Michael</li>
<li class="col-3">Sue</li>?

Comment: No :) This is only the output. You have to use the PHP-Code above `foreach ($a[....]$val.'</li>';}`

Comment: Hi please look at the updated code i edit , with the specific class of each value i need particular functions same with this , but my code seems not working , kindly advise

Comment: Excuse my question but do you already write PHP-code yet? It seams to  you don't understand the concept of PHP

Answer (score 0):

You try this

```
`$no=1;
 foreach ($arrNum as $val) {
 ?>
 <li class="col-<?php echo $no;?>"><?php echo $val; ?></li>
 <?php $no++; } ?>`
```